# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at app.js:3

Tags: javascript, typescript, web3js, go-ethereum

Having issue while connecting front-end HTML to private blockchain in order to interact with the smart contract.

Step completed as below:

- created a smart contract and deployed in pvt blockchain.
- `npm install -g web3`
- created HTML file and linked with below js file.

// Sample app.js file code

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {alert(" web3.currentProvider :: " + web3.currentProvider);
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
 }

 var abi= My-custom-ABI;


 var ins=web3.eth.contract(abi);
 var instance= ins.at("My-Contract-Address");
 var accounts;
 var account;
 var account2;
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of build process or did you refer to the `app.js` file as-is from your HTML page?

Comment: using with typescript, you should follow different syntax, import Web3 = require("web3"); // Note the special syntax! Copy this line when in doubt!

Comment: and also install @types/web3.js using       npm install --dev @types/web3.js

Comment: check this link for more details - https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/README.md#usage-with-typescript

Comment: @NagaSaiA Even though the question is (probably incorrectly) tagged with TypeScript, the shown code is 'normal' ECMAScript/JavaScript.. (anyway, `var abi= My-custom-ABI;` is clearly wrong, but that's a different problem)

Answer (score 0):

You should install it as your dependency, try `npm install --save web3`. Also, you need webpack to transpile your javascript, because browser don't understand `require` syntax.

Comment: npm install --save web3 have installed it locally and globally.Then too issue persist. But i ran the js file using "nodemon" and checked the httml page.

Comment: @Stijin Have not used any build process to refer the js file.

Comment: By using nodemon, that means you're in nodejs environment. So you serve the page using node js. By default, nodejs support require syntax, it shouldn't have any problem with it. Can you provide more information about your package.json? like your npm script. Also, try to make another js file, and require it to see if the problem persist. Like so, var js = require('./another.js')